# how to Pass multiple parameters via Command Parameter in WPF?

Tags: wpf

how to Pass multiple parameters via Command Parameter in WPF?? Do we have to create an object and pass if so can someone help me with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use MultiBinding with a converter that will create an object for you...

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing it would be sufficient to pass the underlying data context to the command? This means you can use sender's DataContext in the command's Executed handler, or set `CommandParameter={Binding}` in xaml.

If you see that you can't bind CommandParameter to a single object - this might be because of a bad design.