# Need additional help with binding multiple CommandParameters using MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multibinding, imultivalueconverter, commandparameter

I need to have a command handler for a ToggleButton that can take multiple parameters, namely the IsChecked property of said ToggleButton, along with a constant value, which could be a string, byte, int... doesn't matter.

I found [this great question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833440/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-via-command-parameter-in-wpf) and followed the answer's link and read up on MultiBinding and IMultiValueConverter.  It went really smoothly until I had to write the MultiBinding, when I realized that I also need to pass a constant value and couldn't do something like

```
<Binding Value="1" />
```

I then came across another [similar question that Kent Boogaart answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350598/passing-two-command-parameters-using-a-wpf-binding), and then I started to think about ways that I could get around this.

One possible way is to not use MVVM and simply add the Tag property to my ToggleButton, in which case my MultiBinding would look like this:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding Path="IsChecked" />
        <Binding Path="Tag" />
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
</MultiBinding>
```

Kent had made a comment along the lines of, "if you're using MVVM you should be able to get around this issue".  However, I'm not sure that's an option for me, even though I have adopted MVVM as my WPF pattern of <strike>necessity</strike> choice.

The reason why I say this is that I have wayyyy more than one ToggleButton in the UserControl, and each of the ToggleButtons' Commands need to call the same function.  But since they are ToggleButtons, I can't use the property bound to IsChecked in the ViewModel, because I don't know which one was last clicked.  I suppose I could add another private property to keep track of this, but it seems a little silly.  As far as the constant goes, I could probably get rid of this if I did the tracking idea, but not sure of any other way to get around it.

Does anyone have good suggestions for me here?  :)

**EDIT** -- ok, so I need to update my bindings, which still don't work quite right:

```
    <ToggleButton Tag="1" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Style="{StaticResource PassFailToggleButtonStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
        <ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                    <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ToggleButton.CommandParameter>
    </ToggleButton>
```

IsChecked was working, but not Tag.  I just realized that Tag is a string... duh.  It's working now!  The key was to use a RelativeSource of **Self**.

Comment: My binding above is wrong, since it's querying the VM.  Anyone have tips, or can you recommend a good online "cheat sheet" for figuring out databinding paths?  I usually look at the output window for errors to see what it's binding to.  Right now, I think I have to set the RelativeSource attribute, but haven't ever used it before.

Comment: ok, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84278/how-do-i-use-wpf-bindings-with-relativesource

Comment: Possible trick for binding to a constant: use a resource.  `<sys:Int32 x:Key="One">1</sys:Int32>` in your Resources section, then `{Binding Source="{StaticResource One}"}`.  Totally untested though.

Comment: Hey that's a nice option, thanks!  The Tag is working fine for me... wonder if there is any sort of performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained above, I figured it out.  I had to use `Self` for `RelativeSource` and that did the trick.